# Nginx Reverse Proxy Won't forward JSON over 100K

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have an Nginx reverse proxy that forwards to a Node.js Express server. Everything works fine unless the JSON payload is over 100K. The node function receives an empty body. I've tried setting the Nginx client_max_body_size to 10M, even though the default is 1M. No errors in the Nginx logs or error logs.

The Nginx Conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1500;
        # multi_accept on;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 3000;

http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600;
        proxy_send_timeout 600;

        client_max_body_size 10M;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/json;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

      access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Site config

```
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.site.com;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires 12h;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_redirect off;
       client_max_body_size 10M;
 }
```

And I'm doing a very simple POST with node-fetch a very simple fetch call. When the body is less than 100K all good, when over the data isn't passed by the reverse proxy:

```
const options = {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  };
fetch(`https://site`, options);
```

Comment: Have you confirmed NGINX is the problem? ie by pass it for testing. NGINX does not care what the body type is FYI. If you are sure NGINX is the issue then check you include files to make sure they are not seting client_max_body_size to some other value.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with nginx. This limit is imposed by express which is by default 100 kb. You can however modify this limit when you're starting your express server.

In your `app.ts`, do:

```
express.json({ limit: "500kb"});
```

if you want to have an upper limit of 500 kb. See [this](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) for more information.